# change the selected tab indicator color of TabLayout(android.support.design.widget)

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I am trying to change the selected tab color of `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` the problem I am facing is that I can't find the method `setSelectedTabIndicatorColor`. In [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorColor%28int%29) it is mentioned but in code it say it can't be resolved. I can change the color in xml using `app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red"`, but i can't figure it out how to change it in JAVA. If i go into the TabLayout class this methord is used with `TabLayout.SlidingTabStrip`, but there is no getter to get the strip and set the color.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment so I'll add it here.

Update the Design Support Library and you'll see the `setSelectedTabIndicatorColor()` method.

This is the line in my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of sliding tab by following code

try this

```
 mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(your color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

Comment: it is tab layout not tab host